# Is there any difference from gardening point of view between the terms of [sod], [turf] and [lawn]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I do not really know outdoor gardening or landscaping but I feel a little redundancy between [sod](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sod) and [lawn](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn) tags. Also there is a tag for [turf](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turf) with the following excerpt:

> Grass and the soil held by the roots. Also known as 'sod'.

- There are [7 questions tagged with both](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sod%20lawn?sort=Newest).
- There are 573 tagged with [lawn](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn).
- There are 31 tagged with [sod](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sod).
- There are 48 questions tagged with [turf](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turf) out of 3 are also tagged as [sod](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sod).

Browsing through some of the questions I found no difference, but again I am not an expert.

I am asking this question as well to either define a tag wiki excerpt for [sod](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sod) tag and possibly update the [lawn](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn) tag too or to merge the tags.

Or just merge [turf](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turf) and [sod](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sod) as they seem to be synonyms by the current excerpt of the turf tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked about the use of turf and sod. I reviewed the use of turf  defined as

> grass and the surface layer of earth held together by its roots

Some of the questions and answers worked well if you substituted lawn for turf. The rest of them, many from users in Europe, used turf as a synonym for sod.  So it seems that turf is used as a synonym for sod and lawn.

I have gone through and retagged some of the 48 turf entries as sod and then merged turf with lawn and made it a synonym of lawn.

I suggest defining these three overlapping terms along the lines of

- lawn as grass or groundcover that is already growing on the ground
- turf is a synonym for lawn so no definition is required
- sod as grass in rolls which must be laid on the ground to grow

  updating post history, 40 rows affected (pipe delimited)
  updating posts, 37 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
  updating PostTags associations, 18 rows affected
  destroying 'turf': [turf] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
  total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
  0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
  0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
  updating count for target tag, new count: 592
  tag remapping of [lawn] and [turf] complete!
  remapping 0 synonyms
  1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
  0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
  Tag Synonym turf -> lawn was approved!

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod)

> Sod also known as turf is grass. When harvested into rolls it is held
> together by its roots and a thin layer of soil.
>
> In Australian and British English, sod is more commonly known as turf,
> and the word "sod" is limited mainly to agricultural senses.

and [Lawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawn)

> A lawn is an area of soil-covered land planted with grasses and other
> durable plants such as clover which are maintained at a short height
> with a lawnmower (or sometimes grazing animals) and used for aesthetic
> and recreational purposes.

As it is used in North America you mow the lawn and you lay sod.  There is a short period of time after it is just laid that you water the sod but once it is established it is considered to be a lawn.

Sod could be considered the same as a perennial in a pot.  It must be planted before it can grow so it is not the same as a lawn. It does not relate to planting grass seed or lawn maintenance.

What do you see for content in the sod questions?